# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/why-does-isis-prefer-to-attack-european-capitals-instead-of-israel

While the wording of the question could use improvement (or more bluntly, jew-hatin' conspiracy theory ought to be edited out), the premise of the question itself is meaningful and definitely answerable with facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not the one who deleted it, but I can offer some explanation.

The question was asked by a new user whose username matched the real name of an [active Stack Exchange user](http://stackexchange.com/users/510256/asaf-karagila?tab=accounts) from Israel. The combination of this fact with the content of the question strongly suggested that intentional impersonation was going on, and that the question was asked in bad faith.

Since it was also a low quality question that drew a low-quality non-answer, deletion was an easy way out of the mess. Anyone interested in the topic can always ask their own, less inflammatory, version of the question. Chances are that the discussion of a sensitive subject will be more successful when not initiated by a troll.

Comment: The linked web page also says someone tried to impersonate them on Quora. Thanks, that explains it